# addClass is removed from button when clicking inside Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

The button that activates the dropdown uses click rather than hover, on click, I've used jquery to add class, and to remove the class when clicked outside the button I used  $(document).click. The problem is, when I click inside the dropdown menu, the class gets removed (Which will obviously happen)

Is there anyway to make an exception for the dropdown div or is there any fix I can use to solve the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".menu1TextContainer").click(function(event){

     $(".menu1Container").toggleClass("addclass")
     event.preventDefault();

 });

$(document).click(function(event) {
      if(!$(event.target).is(".menu1TextContainer")){
        $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
      }
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9j3k61rg/3/

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you want toggleClass instead?

Comment: Can you try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just simply need to skip class adding/removing when your dropdown is open. I have made a working code for you:

I updated your snippet, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3k61rg/4/

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).is(".menu1TextContainer") && !$(event.target).is("#menu1Dropdown")) {
         $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
     }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose not to do removeClass by checking the clicked element's id.

You can check it like this -

```
if (event.target.id != "menu1Dropdown") {
           $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
         }
```

Full working snippet below.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".menu1TextContainer").click(function(event) {
     $(".menu1Container").addClass("addclass")
     event.preventDefault();
   });

   $(document).click(function(event) {
     if (event.target.id != "menu1Dropdown") {
       $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
     }
   });

 });

 $(function() {

   // Dropdown toggle
   $('.menu1Container').click(function() {
     $(this).next('#menu1Dropdown').slideToggle(100);
   });

   $(document).click(function(e) {
     var target = e.target;
     if (!$(target).is('.menu1') && !$(target).parents().is('.menu1')) {
       $('#menu1Dropdown').slideUp(100);
     }
   });

 });

 $(function() {

   // Dropdown toggle
   $('.menu2Container').click(function() {
     $(this).next('#menu2Dropdown').slideToggle(100);
   });

   $(document).click(function(e) {
     var target = e.target;
     if (!$(target).is('.menu2') && !$(target).parents().is('.menu2')) {
       $('#menu2Dropdown').slideUp(100);
     }
   });

 });
```

```css
/* Menu 1 */

.menu1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 67px;
  top: 43px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 99px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu1Container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 99px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu1TextContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 99px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}


/* Menu 1 Drop Down */

#menu1Dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  top: 83px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: none;
}


/* Menu 1 Drop Down End */

.addclass {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu1">

  <div class="menu1Container">
    <p class="menu1TextContainer" id="btn">BUTTON1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="menu1Dropdown">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try by changing below code

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
            if (!$(event.target).is(".menu1TextContainer") && (!$(event.target).is("#menu1Dropdown"))) {
                $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip removing "addclass" when dropdown is clicked.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
     if (!$(event.target).is(".menu1TextContainer") && !$(event.target).is("#menu1Dropdown")) {
         $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your JS with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".menu1TextContainer").click(function(event){

         $(".menu1Container").toggleClass("addclass")
         event.preventDefault();

     });

 $("*:not(.menu1Container)").click(function(event) {

            $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive

        });

});
```

I hope that's the desired effect..

Answer (score 0):

my solution is different from one of "@herrsiim". The reason is event bubbling up => my solution is preventing bubbling:

At line 32 of javascript, when you are sliding your dropdown, change from:

```
$(this).next('#menu1Dropdown').slideToggle(100);
```

to:

```
$(this).next('#menu1Dropdown').slideToggle(100).click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

That is the same effect of "@herrsiim"

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you.
What this does actually is that it removes 'addclass' if dropdown is opened.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).is(".menu1TextContainer") && !$(event.target).is("#menu1Dropdown")) {
         $(".menu1Container").removeClass("addclass"); //make all inactive
     }
        });

});
```

I hope I helped. If something is not clear enough please feel free to ask.